# C#のMath.Roundで小数の四捨五入がおかしいケース

Tags: c#, .net

Math.Round(316.226184874055d, 11);
としたとき、 316.22618487405  が返ってきます。
11桁を指定したので、12桁の5が繰り上がることで、最後が 406 となるのを期待していたのですが、切り捨てのような動作でした。
C#ではこのようになってしまうケースがある、という感じなのでしょうか？

みなさん、ありがとうございます。
丸める直前まではdouble特有の誤差が必要だったので、丸め処理だけ一旦、
Math.Round((decimal)doubleの変数);として、返値をdouble型にすることで解決しました。

double test1 = 316.226184874055d;
double test2 = (double)Math.Round((decimal)test1, 11, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
※test2の値はdouble型で316.22618487406になりました。

IEEE754準拠とdouble特有の誤差、銀行型の丸めという３つの要素があるとのことで、406を期待した理由から考え直して予想してみました。
MS-DOSの時代にコンパイルされたEXEの計算挙動を調べていたというのが「C#の四捨五入がなぜ違うのか」と思った原因でもありました。
そのEXEは数値の扱いがdouble型の挙動でしたが計算式の結果値を64ビットよりも少ない有効桁数に丸める特徴（仕様）があったので、計算式中と結果値の桁数をそれぞれ調べていたところ　SQRT(99999)が316.22618487406　と表示されるので丸め方を予測していたところ、どうしても11桁での四捨五入で最後の4055の5が繰り上がっているとしか思えなかったのです。

丸め方がCPUにdoubleを扱わせるのとは関係ないのであれば、当時は丸め方の方針そのものがコンパイラメーカー又はEXEを作った人の独自実装だったのかもしれないので、IEEE754や銀行型丸めでもなく、一般的な四捨五入となるように実装されていたのかもしれません。（double型特有の誤差を無くしての四捨五入を実装する方が、逆に大変そうですが・・・）

Comment: i386の時代だと、FPUが内部的にdoubleを80bitに拡張して計算していたため、二重丸めが起きてdoubleのLSBがひとつずれるという現象もありました(最適化の有無で結果が異なったりします)。丸めが予想と異なる結果を返す理由はいくつもありえますが、結局のところ、ライブラリの設計時にどういう用途を想定しているかに依存し、何が「正しい」かはライブラリの設計方針に照らさないと判断できません。10進数で厳密な丸め挙動が必要であれば、それを保証するライブラリを使う必要がある、ということになるかと思います。

Comment: 設計方針が新たなものであればいいのですが、過去の資産と同様に、となると非常に深いところが問題になってくるようで、すみません。

「10進数で厳密な丸め挙動」に見えたEXEの挙動が、偶然「FPUが内部的にdoubleを80bitに拡張して計算していたため、二重丸めが起きてdoubleのLSBがひとつずれるという現象」の一例だったかもしれない・・・
相当数の例から予測を出していかないと「何のふるまい」かがわからない深い問題だったようでした。
丸めには様々な仕様があり、double演算ではハードウェア的なふるまいも加味される可能性がわかりました。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 6):

10進数の316.226184874055は、2進数では正確に表現できません。最も近い倍精度浮動小数点数を選ぶと、それは316.226184874055よりわずかに小さな数になります(*1)。従って、11桁目での丸めとしては316.22618487405の方が316.22618487406より近いのです。

もうすこし細かい話としては、「2進数の数値を10進数のx桁で丸め、結果を2進数の数値で得る」というのは厳密な意味での「丸め」でありません。結果の桁数が減らないからです。10進数での丸めが必要ならば、最初から10進数で扱い、結果も10進数で得る必要があります (BLUEPIXYさんの回答のようにdecimal型を使うのはその例となります。) 詳しくは次の記事をどうぞ。

http://blog.practical-scheme.net/shiro/20131229-flonum-rounding

(*1) 316.226184874055に最も近い倍精度浮動小数点数の値は 695388734552533/2199023255552 で、これは10進数での正確な値  316226184874055/1000000000000 より小さい

Answer (score 6):

質問にある`316.226184874055`に関してはshirokさんの回答通りですが、その他に[Math.Round()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/75ks3aby(v=vs.100).aspx)は正確には四捨五入ではなく銀行型丸めです。解説にあるように`2.135`は`2.13`へ切り捨てられます。四捨五入を行うには同解説の

> 丸めの種類を制御するには、Math.Round(Double, Int32, MidpointRounding) オーバーロードを呼び出します。

に従う必要があります。

---

shirokさんの書かれた値をWindowsの電卓で計算してみました。
69538873455253**3**/2199023255552 = 316.2261848740**549**7944564558565617
69538873455253**4**/2199023255552 = 316.2261848740**554**3419299647212029
ということで`316.226184874055`に最も近い値は前者ですね。

Comment: MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero で一般的な四捨五入のモードにできますね。https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms131275(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @yhata はい、その点も解説に書かれていたので省略してしまいました。加筆しておきます。

Comment: MSDNの解説にも書かれていますが、銀行型丸めとしては2.135は2.14に切り上げられるのが正しいので、2.13へ切り捨てられてしまうのはこれとは別の問題です。`MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`を指定したところで2.14に切り上げられることはありません。 https://dotnetfiddle.net/7TtRYO

Answer (score 0):

`double` の表現精度は１５桁で、`316.226184874055`は１５桁なので保持する数値を内部的に(内部的には１７桁ある)正しく表現できていないのではないかと思います。
このような場合(数の表現桁数が限度に近い場合、浮動小数の表現に正確性を求められる場合)には、decimal型を使うのがいいかと思います。

例：
`Math.Round(316.226184874055m, 11);`//=>316.22618487406

Comment: 10進数での表現精度はこのケースでは関係ないです。たとえば"0.15" は10進数で2桁ですが、2進数で正確に表現できず、最も近い2進数は0.15よりわずかに小さくなるので、2進数で丸め操作をやると10進数でみて一見おかしい動作が起きる可能性があります。

Comment: @shirok  そうですね。浮動小数の表現が正確で無い場合があるというのは知っております。そういう意味で説明が足りなかったかもしれません。ちなみに`Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(0.15d, 1))`は`0.2`になります。

Comment: 「doubleの表現精度が17桁」というのは、「2進数を10進数で表現した際に、17桁まで表示しておけば、表現可能な全てのdoubleの浮動小数点数を区別できる」ということです。「17桁までの10進数が区別できる」ということではありません。

Comment: @shirok  そんな主張はしていませんが。

Comment: お気に触ったら済みません。今回の議論で「doubleの表示精度が15～17桁であること」は全く関係ない、と言う点には同意いただけるでしょうか。

Comment: `Math.Round(0.15d, 1)` が`0.2`になることはどう説明するのですか？

Comment: あ、別の可能性に気づきました。Math.Round(5.015d, 2)はどうなりますか? これが5.02になるなら、内部的に10進数表現に直して処理している可能性がありますね。だとすれば10進数表現の精度は影響がありますので、「関係ない」というコメントを撤回します。

Comment: うーん、5.02ではなく5.01になりますが、それが内部処理を確かめることにはならないような気がします。

Comment: @shirok 私の回答にも書きましたが、Math.Roundの実装では10のdigit乗をかけて整数に丸めて10のdigit乗で割る、ということをしているだけですので、「内部的に10進数表現に直して処理している」ってことはないです。10進での表現精度は確かに関係ないと思います。

Comment: 2進浮動小数点数の「10倍」はそれだけで内部で丸めが入るので丸め処理中に使うのは禁忌なんですが(二重丸めが生じる可能性があるので)、「2進数を10進n桁で『丸め』る」という操作自体がill-definedなのであまり気にしないって方針ですかね。0.15dのケースは多分この二重丸めが大きい方に出たんじゃないかな。

Answer (score 0):

浮動小数点数の内部表現誤差によるものです。C#に限らず多くの言語で再現すると思われます。(多くの環境で[IEEE 754](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)という標準規格に準拠した内部表現が使われているためです。)

なお、小数部桁数指定版のMath.Round(double value, int digit)の[実装](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs)では、value * 10<sup>digit</sup>を整数に丸め、10<sup>digit</sup>で割る、という処理を行っています。

そして、今回の数値の実際の内部値が正確にどうなっているか追いかけてみます。
(実数の10進表現→浮動小数2進表現は一般に正確に変換できませんが、浮動小数2進表現→10進表現は厳密に正確に行うことが可能です。今回は[Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)氏の[DoubleConverter](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs)を使用させていただきました。)

矢印の右側が正確な値です。
316.226184874055 → 316.22618487405497944564558565616607666015625
316.22618487405497944564558565616607666015625 * 10<sup>11</sup> → 31622618487405.49609375
これを丸めると 31622618487405。内部表現誤差による影響が出ていることがわかります。

もう少し進めると、
31622618487405 / 10<sup>11</sup> → 316.2261848740499772247858345508575439453125
つまり厳密には`Math.Round(316.226184874055d, 11);`の結果は316.2261848740499772247858345508575439453125です。
これをdouble.ToString()などで普通に文字列化すると15桁に丸められ、316.226184874050。
最後の0を省略して316.22618487405となります。

[確認用 .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Inkug4)